# missing template in rails when correct view, controller and route exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to create an easy app in rails.

I have a controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

I have a view (Broadway/app/views/pages.html.erb)

and I have a route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

but when I start my server at http://localhost:3000/

I get error

```
PagesController#home is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats:
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try making `Broadway/app/views/pages/home.html.erb`. The name of the template should match the name of the controller action. Right now, your template is NOT matching the name of the controller.

Comment: Please confirm you put `home.html.erb` in the `app/view/pages` directory. Also, it *might* help if you add the text of your actual stack track to your original question.

Comment: You might also need to check if your request or response is in HTML format, either way might use the wrong template if Rails JSON default might look into JBuilder

Comment: @akr , jvillians answer is right. You still get the same error most probably because you only renamed ‘pages.html.erb’ to ‘home.html.erb’ without moving it inside ‘views/pages/‘ directory.  Your file is currently located inside ‘/views’. Fix that and you re good to go.